# Generated React test snapshots don't match on local Mac and CI build server

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storybook, reactxp

We are using [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org) along with its [StoryShots addon](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/release/3.4/addons/storyshots) to visualize and test our ReactXP components.

Recently, the CI job that runs the tests on those StoryShots started failing with snapshots that don't match.

Turns out that when we update the snapshots from our Mac development environment, the snapshots include a `webkitFlexDirection` style whereas the snapshots generated by the CI environment (docker image based on `node:9`) don't have this attribute:

[image: screenshot]

I have no idea where this `webkitFlexDirection` comes from and why it is present in the snapshots generated on my Mac but not in the snapshots generated within the test Docker image.

I have searched for `webkitFlexDirection` in many top-level repos (React, ReactXP, Jest, Storybook, StoryShots, ...) and found nothing.

I suppose that `react-test-renderer` uses some library to produce the snapshot, and that library would be the one responsible for generating (or not) the `webkitFlexDirection` attribute, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is it happening for some component in particular? Perhaps it is a library that adds that attribute for some reason?

Comment: It happens for all our components.

Comment: I suspect the answer is in this code in the `ReactXP` library: https://github.com/Microsoft/reactxp/blob/master/src/web/Styles.ts#L139

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I’ll have a look.